# Db2 error during enlarge of a column which is in the primary key

Tags: db2, db2-luw

I'm using Db2 11.5.4000.1449 on window 10.

I have the table `THETABLE` with those columns:

```
THEKEY CHAR(30) NOT NULL
THEDATA CHAR(30)
```

Primary key: `THEKEY`

I try to enlarge the primary key column using the following statement:

```
ALTER TABLE THETABLE ALTER COLUMN THEKEY SET DATA TYPE CHAR(50)
```

But I got the error:

> SQLCODE=-668, SQLSTATE=57007 reason code="7"

[The official IBM documentation says which the table is in reorg pending state](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/how-verify-and-resolve-sql0668n-reason-code-7-when-accessing-table)

The table is NOT in reorg pending state.

I've check using:

```
SELECT REORG_PENDING FROM SYSIBMADM.ADMINTABINFO 
where TABSCHEMA='DB2ADMIN' and tabname='THETABLE'
```

The results of the below query is: N

I've tried to reorg both the table and indexes but the problem persists.

The only way I have found is to drop the primary key, alter the column and then add the primary key.

Note:

I have also other tables in which I've enlarged a `CHAR` column which is a primary key. (without dropping and recreate the primary key)

The problems does not come for all tables but only for some tables.
I have no idea why for some table is possible to enlarge a `CHAR` column which is a primary and and for some other tables not.

Have you any idea?

Comment: The answer will be in the information you omitted from your question. The -668 sqlcode always has a __reason code__ to accompany it (may appear as sqlerrmc), and it gives the precise reason explanation when you run `db2 "? SQL0668N" | more `.  You can see the reason code if you try the reorg from the CLP command line, or if you look in the db2diag.log, or get the full error message from whatever tool you use to submit the reorg command.

Comment: Your're right. Reason code is: "7". Means which table is in reorg pending state.
But as I had said in the my post is NOT in reorg pending state.

Comment: Regardless of the information returned by ADMINTABINFO, have you performed a `reorg ` on that table, ensured the reorg completed successfully?  If the reorg completes successfully, and the subsequent 'alter table' to widen the column gives the same symptom, then open a ticket with IBM Db2 support. They may ask you to apply fixpack 11.5.6.0 and retry.

Comment: The fact that you are enlarging the PK is a red flag. Why do you want to do this in the first place? The PK only function is to be a unique row identifier. It doesn't need to be sexy or good looking. In fact their values are not important since they are not shown in the UI or exposed to the public. If you are exposing them (seems like) then use a secondary UNIQUE column (a relational property) instead. The PK should be a simple numeric [internal] value.